# Grid template area not respected in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-grid

On Edge, the content does not respect the defined areas when some are empty.
I want if there's only one offer, it doesn't exceed 1/4.

Works on Chrome/FF

I have:

```
grid-template-areas: "offer offer offer offer";
grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
grid-gap: 1rem;
```

[See the CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/geBQQX) on Chrome/FF and Edge

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "offer offer offer offer";
  grid-gap: 7px;
}

.offer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="offer">Offer 1</div>
  <div class="offer">Offer 2</div>
  <div class="offer">Offer 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your issue. For fixing it you should submit this bug to [MS issue tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/).

But if you are looking for workarounds, you can set grid columns' width explicitly using `grid-template-columns`, in current case `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)`. Demo:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "offer offer offer offer";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 7px;
}

.offer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="offer">Offer 1</div>
  <div class="offer">Offer 2</div>
  <div class="offer">Offer 3</div>
</div>
```